# send answer to server, and retrieve relevant array from server back for next input options

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to get the following to work: I would like to send an answer to a drop-down menu question to a php script, which in turn will give me back a new selection from the database. I then want to use this new selection to change the available input options in a secondary drop-down menu

The end goal is to limit the selection options from around 200 (day care centers) to about 15, by providing a preliminary limitation (chosing your municipality)

for reference "gem(eente)" is municipality

stripped down the javascript/ajax part that I have so far is this:

```
function loadXMLDoc(str) {
      var xmlhttp;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
         {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
         xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
         }
      else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                 {
                 document.getElementById("gemeente").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                 }
           }
      xmlhttp.open("POST","http:www.doenwatikkan.nl/jeroen/dynamic.php",true);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xmlhttp.send(gem);
      alert(gem)
           }
```

the php part is this

```
<?php
include 'dbconnection.php';
$gem=$_POST["gem"];
$gennam=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM psz WHERE Gemeente='$gem'");
echo "ik ben in dit php script geweest";
$test="willekeurige string";
?>
```

and the relevant html/php part is the following:

```
<select name="pszplaats" id="gemeente" onchange="fdisplay();loadXMLDoc(this.value)">
    <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($selectgem)){?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['Gemeente']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Gemeente'];?>
    </option>
     <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <select name="psznaam" id="test" style="display:none">
    <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($gennam)){?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['NaamPSZ']; ?>"><?php echo $row['NaamPSZ'];?>
    </option>
     <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

the alert(gem) part in the javascript works, so if people select an option for minucupality, it shows up on screen, but the "echo" in the php part doesn't show anything, so Im thinking the ajax doesn't look at my php properly.

Could anybody please tell me what idiotic mistake I am making, because I can't figure it out.
thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it go in success callback? i.e. Do you see any reply in `document.getElementById("gemeente").innerHTML`?

Answer (score 1):

I've just fired a quick request at the PHP script you've got in the back there, and it's outputting the contents of echo fine.

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","http:www.doenwatikkan.nl/jeroen/dynamic.php",true);
```

The URL above appears to be missing '//' after 'http:' and I'd suppose your browser will be making a request to `current_url/http:www...', which of course won't work.

Comment: hmm, that seems to have fixed part of it. Still don't see the echo, but now the input for the first drop-down menu disappears after it's selected. is this because the browser reloads that selection only, rather than the second select?

Comment: There are more fundamental issues to resolve here, perhaps beyond the scope of a single question. You're replacing the contents of the first select with a string at the moment (which of course won't work) - what you probably mean to do is alter the second drop down (with a different id if you look at your own source) and to return a series of <option> tags from the PHP script in the background.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. How far off am I on that goal? I actually wasn't even trying to change the input of the first select, just the second select. Does that mean that the specific javascript function can only apply to changing the content of that particular input field?

Comment: 'document.getElementById("gemeente").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;' - this line explicitly changes the element with the id 'gemeente', which is the first select. Of course to alter another you'd replace the id as appropriate.

Comment: okay cool, I think I'm getting a bit more about the entire process. Now if I want to return a new array from the server in a useable format, rather than simple text, is this possible? Or should I make a new thread for such a question? Since I'm a newby here, I'm not sure how to go about these issues ;)